# Merge several files with maximum 1 line difference

Tags: shell, diff, merge

Suppose I have the following files:

file0.c:

```
int b=NULL;
int a=NULL;
```

file1.c:

```
int b;
int a=NULL;
```

file2.c:

```
int b;
int a=NULL;
```

I am looking to merge the files file1 and file2 to generate the following result.c:

```
int b;
int a;
```

I can use : `diff input0 input1` and `diff input0 input2` to get the line+column combinations, however I don't know what to do next in order to achieve the above results.

Comment: Is each number supposed to be a line? If so then writem them as lines. There are two differences, not just one. Maybe a typo.

Comment: I have made changes to make the problem more understandable, one solution could be to get the line number from diff and then replace using sed?

Comment: diff -D00-11 file0.c file1.c > merged.c and edit away the resulting #ifdef and unwanted lines. (assuming you are working with only small differences.)

Comment: Your files are exactly equal...

Comment: If they were supposed to have `= NULL` on one variable each, what is to say that the result is as you state, or each variable having the `= NULL`? Some kind of majority vote? Whatever the answer, it is quite unlikely to have a simple solution; unless you need to do this regularly or for huge files, do it by hand, that'll be less work on the end.

Comment: Achieve what results? It looks like you want to delete all lines where a variable is set to something. Please [edit] your question and make your examples (and file names) consistent with what you want to do.

Comment: Why does the result file have "int a;" instead of "int a=NULL;"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `file2.c` should be:

```
int b=NULL;
int a;
```

rather than a copy of `file1.c`.

With that change, what we can understand is that `file0.c` is a common ancestor (the "merge base") for `file1.c` and `file2.c`, which each fix half of the bug of using `NULL` to initialize `int` variables.

If the changes weren't so close together, we could use `diff3 -m file1.c file0.c file2.c`. Alas, that will just output a conflict marker.

However, if we know that what is going on is nothing but one-line substitutions—that is, no lines are being added, removed or or moved, only fixed in place—we can obtain the two deltas 0-1 and 0-2 as `ed` script diffs with `diff -e`. We can catenate these scripts and then use `ed` to apply them.

First, let's make a copy of `file0.c` called `test.c`. We will try to apply those changes to `test.c`:

```
$ cp file0.c test.c
```

Now, let's collect the `ed` style patches:

```
$ (diff -e file0.c file1.c ; diff -e file0.c file2.c) > patch
```

What do they look like?

```
$ cat patch
1c
int b;
.
2c
int a;
.
```

That looks an awful lot like the correct commands to turn `test.c` into the desired merged file. What's missing is the `wq` to save:

```
$ echo wq >> patch
```

Now let's try it:

```
$ cat test.c
int b=NULL;
int a=NULL;
$ ed test.c < patch
ed test.c < patch
24
14
$ cat test.c
int b;
int a;
```

Done.